# browser extension shared indexedDB data

Tags: firefox-addon, indexeddb, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am currently in the middle of developing a browser extension on firefox. I noticed that when an extension is being deployed in machine level (on Windows), it uses different indexedDB database for different windows users on the same machine.

Is there any way for me to sync up the data so that different users on the machine share the same IndexedDB data?

Comment: It is per origin, so you would have to figure out how to share the origin.

Comment: Are there currently any best practice done to do this?

Comment: Have each user individually sync with server side state, e.g. pouchdb/couchdb